# Changing Background Based off of Time of Day and Day of Week?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to have a background that changes based off of the day of the week, and the time of day. I've seen similar questions here but none are giving me any ideas of where I'm going wrong.

#### CSS:

```
    <style type="text/css">
    img.bg {
        min-height: 100%;
        min-width: 1024px;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
        img.bg {
            left: 50%;
            margin-left: -512px;
        }
    }
</style>
```

#### Script:

```
function setbkg(){
    var d = new Date(),
    w = d.getDay(),
    h = d.getHours(),
    i;
        if(w = 0) {
            if (h = 0 || h = 1 || h = 14 || h = 15) i = "img/one.png";
            else if (h = 2 || h = 3 || h = 6 || h = 7 || h = 20 || h = 22 || h = 23) i = "img/two.png";
            else i = "img/three.png";
        }
        else if(w = 1) {
            if (h = 0 || h = 1) i = "img/one.png";
            else if (h = 2 || h = 3 || h = 6 || h = 7) i = "img/two.png";
            else if (h = 12 || h = 13) i = "img/three.png";
            else if (h = 22 || h = 23) i = "img/four.png";
            else i = "img/five.png";
        }
        else if(w = 2 || w = 3 || w = 4 || w = 5) {
            if (h = 0 || h = 1 || h = 12 || h = 13) i = "img/one.png";
            else if (h = 2 || h = 3 || h = 6 || h = 7 || h = 22 || h = 23) i = "img/two.png";
            else i = "img/three.png";
        }
        else if(w = 6){
            if (h = 0 || h = 1) i = "img/one.png";
            else if (h = 2 || h = 3 || h = 6 || h = 7) i = "img/two.png";
            else if (h = 14 || h = 15) i = "img/three.png";
            else if (h = 20 || h = 22 || h = 23) i = "img/four.png";
            else i = "img/five.png";
        }
        else{ i = "i.imgur.com/wNOr5VU.png" }

        document.write('<img src="' + i + '" class="bg">');
    }
```

And after the head,

```
<body onload="setbkg()">
```

I'm sure this is a very inefficient way of trying to accomplish this, but I'm still a beginner. Right now, nothing happens and I get a white screen. Thoughts?

Comment: sanity check, but is the img directory within the same dir as where the webpage loads resources from?  This has tripped me up before

Comment: Good question. Yes, this is index.html on the root of the server, and there's one folder in the root called img which contains the files.

Comment: since it is live can u link us to it ? Also, why is the day of week important ? If your open to ideas, Time of day and weather seems more fun :)                  Also check this link it may help you simplify some stuff http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/timeback.shtml

Comment: use developer tools and try putting a console.log in the javascript functions to see if they are getting called.  Also check if the `<img src="...">` tag is ever applied to the page even if it doesn't display how you expect it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each if block you are using "=" operator. It's assignment operator. Use "==" in each if condition and your code will work.

The the following is the smaller version of your code. And it's working properly. I've just kept two images in the same directory with index.html.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test main</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <style type="text/css">
        img.bg {
            min-height: 100%;
            min-width: 1024px;
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            position: fixed;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
            img.bg {
                left: 50%;
                margin-left: -512px;
            }
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        function setbkg(){
            var d = new Date(),
            w = d.getDay(),
            h = d.getHours(),
            i;
            if(w == 3) {

                i = "body-img.jpg";

            }
            else{ i = "large.jpg" }

            document.write('<img src="' + i + '" class="bg">');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="setbkg()">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use document.write in the body onload . By the time it's called the document is already loaded so where will it write it? (Undefined...)

Try some dom manipulations, for instance adding the img to a div:

```
<div id="myBackground"></div>

var container = document.getElementById("myBackground");
container.innerHTML = '<img src="">';
```